# VS Code cannot open iostream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Why is my VS Code giving the error of updating #include path and what does it mean? It writes that it cannot open `iostream` source file. I have successfully installed all extensions and included path too.

Comment: what operating system are you on? what c++ compilers have you installed and how did you install them? what vscode extensions do you have installed? what are your vscode project settings like? have you read vscode's documentation for getting started with c++ development on your platform?

Comment: Also what does your code look like?